# When trying to make a matrix in r in keeping getting this error, Error in mde(x) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to plot a matrix in r but keep getting this error:

> Error in mde(x) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.

My code is:

```
library(igraph)
matrix1 <- read.table("matrix1.txt", header=T)
matix1 <- as.matrix(matrix1)

firstmatrix <- graph.adjacency(matrix1, mode="directed", weighted=NULL)
```

> Error in mde(x) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

```
plot(firstmatrix)
```

> Error in plot(firstmatrix) : object 'firstmatrix' not found.

anyone know how to fix this?
thanks

Comment: Is it correct `matix1 <- as.matrix(matrix1)` ? Or should it be `matrix1 <- as.matrix(matrix1)` ?

Comment: thank you didnt see the typo

Comment: Did this solve your problem ?